# How to store directory structure in .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I wish to have a .NET assembly have a directory containing files and folders in it. The reason is that at runtime, this file/folder structure is created into a temporary directory. What is the best practice?

Should I store each file in a resource and have some sort of XML file mapping each filename to the relative directory to which it is supposed to be extracted?

Should I make a .zip file and store that .zip file in a resources? (Outside of this usage, I do not need a decompression library for my assembly, however.)

Comment: Do you want to store the actual files, or just file metadata?

Comment: Are you just copying the files to a working folder?

Comment: I am copying the files to a working folder.

Comment: Then for each file, just call File.Copy().  Storing the files themselves in memory will quickly run you out of memory if there is any significant size or volume of files.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Okay, I hadn't appreciated that you needed the files as well as the directory structure.

Embedding it all within a zip file does seem to be the simplest approach, to be honest. Alternatively, you *could* include each file separately within the assembly and *also* have a structure file, for example:

```
<folder name="root">
  <file resource="Foo.Bar.File1" name="file.txt" />
  <folder name="child">
    <file resource="Foo.Bar.File2" name="foo.jpg" />
  </folder>
</folder>
```

I think that will get somewhat messy though - particularly if you have a lot of files. If it's just a few, it wouldn't be too bad...

Comment: This won't store the files themselves.

Comment: I need the actual files in addition to their directory layout.

Comment: @dodexahedron: Indeed - I hadn't appreciated that part of the question.

Comment: +1. I like the idea of just .zip-ing the files and folders you need,and embedding them as an assembly resource. Then you can read them back as a byte[] and un-zip them.